# Model is infeasible in Gurobi although it has a feasible solution

Tags: gurobi, quadratic

I am attempting to solve a non-convex quadratic optimization problem using Gurobi, but I have encountered an issue. Specifically, I have a specific objective function; however, I am only interested in finding a feasible solution. To do this, I tried two ways:

1- set my specific objective function as the model objective and set the parameter "SolutionLimit" to 1. This works fine, and Gurobi gives me a feasible solution.

2- give Gurobi no objective function (or set the objective to some arbitrary number like 0). In this case, Gurobi returns no feasible solution. The log it prints says:

```
Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Warning: max constraint violation (1.5757e+01) exceeds tolerance
         (model may be infeasible or unbounded - try turning presolve off)
Best objective -0.000000000000e+00, best bound -0.000000000000e+00, gap 0.0000%
```

I checked the solution it returned, and it is infeasible. I want the second method to work too. I have attempted to modify the solver parameters (such as "m.ModelSense = GRB.MAXIMIZE," "m.params.MIPFocus = 3," "m.params.NoRelHeurTime = 200," "m.params.DualReductions = 0," "m.params.Presolve = 2," and "m.params.Crossover = 0") in an effort to resolve this issue but have been unsuccessful. Are there any other parameters that I can adjust in order to successfully solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model has numerical issues; to understand more, please see [Guidelines for Numerical Issues](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/guidelines_for_numerical_i.html) in the Gurobi Reference Manual.

Comment: By adjusting the parameters `m.params.Presolve` to 0 and `m.params.NumericFocus` to 1, 2, or 3, I was able to alleviate the issue to a certain degree. For less complex instances, these parameter settings may result in a successful solution; however, for more complex instances, the solver is still unable to find a feasible solution, despite the existence of one.

Best,
Samira